# xubuntu 13.10 boots to black screen after grub

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, resolution

I know this is a common theme, but all of the other similar threads I've found were either based on a clear change (e.g., upgrading), or were unsolved. I'm a relative newcomer to linux, but have a nice xubuntu setup that's been working delightfully for a few months until just recently.

After selecting ubuntu from grub (I dual boot Windows 7) I get the regular blue loading screen, then black. I can get to a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>, so I have hope, but not much idea of what to do.

Booting into recovery mode works, sort of. I get a low resolution GUI and can open a terminal, but any graphical applications I try to launch (like mousepad or the settings manager) open in a window too small to do or see anything, which I cannot resize, so it's not particularly useful.

The only possible cause I can think of for this issue is that right before the problem began I plugged my computer into a projector and messed around with the display settings and resolution to make that work. So, if anyone knows how to reset default display settings from terminal that might be a helpful start.

Computer is a two year old Thinkpad t420, native resolution 1600x900, if that's any help.

Thanks!